# Can't use Shadcn components

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I've created a basic tailwind + react app. I'm trying to use Shadcn as well but am getting this error when trying to use a button component:
 `ERROR in ./src/pages/homepage/index.js 5:0-48 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/ui/button' in ...`

I have a jsconfig.json file instead of a tsconfig because I'm not using typescript

How do I fix this?

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5EIw.png)

app.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Index } from './pages/homepage/index';
function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                {/* public routes */}
                <Route path='/' element={ <Index /> } />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"

export function Index() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline text-cyan-600">
                Hello world!
            </h1>
            <Button variant="outline">Button</Button>
        </>
    )
}
```

jsconfig.json - from the example next js app:
https://github.com/shadcn/next-template-jsx/blob/main/jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

have also tried it with this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
        "@/*": ["./src/*"]
      }
    }
  }
```

components.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "rsc": false,
  "tsx": false,
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "src/index.css",
    "baseColor": "slate",
    "cssVariables": true
  },
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}
```

Not sure what to do, I'm pretty sure I followed all of the steps correctly - I installed using the new CLI. It looks similar to other repos I've seen

Everything is the latest versions

edit:
these are the CLI questions

```
Would you like to use TypeScript (recommended)? no/yes
Which style would you like to use? › Default
Which color would you like to use as base color? › Slate
Where is your global CSS file? › › app/globals.css
Do you want to use CSS variables for colors? › no / yes
Where is your tailwind.config.js located? › tailwind.config.js
Configure the import alias for components: › @/components
Configure the import alias for utils: › @/lib/utils
Are you using React Server Components? › no / yes
```

and my answers:

```
no
default
slate
src/index.css
yes
tailwind.config.js
@/components
@/lib/utils
no
```

Answer (score 9):

For **(*reactjs + javascript + tailwindcss*):**

**1st:** `npm create vite@latest`

**2nd:** `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer` `npx tailwindcss init -p`

**3rd:** created jsconfig.json manually in root folder.

**4th:** added this lines in jsconfig.json

```
      {
        "compilerOptions": {
          "paths": {
          "@/*": ["./*"]
          }
        }
      }
```

**5th:** `npx shadcn-ui@latest init`

When executed, I have selected all those:

```
Would you like to use TypeScript (recommended)? no
Which style would you like to use? › Default
Which color would you like to use as base color? › Slate
Where is your global CSS file? › src/index.css
Do you want to use CSS variables for colors? › no
Where is your tailwind.config.js located? › tailwind.config.js
Configure the import alias for components: › @/components
Configure the import alias for utils: › @/lib/utils
Are you using React Server Components? › no
```

In the end, the console will ask to save it in **components.json**. Press Y.

Inside **`components.json`** will look like this.(look for aliases)

```
   {
    "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
    "style": "default",
    "rsc": false,
    "tsx": false,
    "tailwind": {
      "config": "tailwind.config.js",
      "css": "src/index.css",
      "baseColor": "slate",
      "cssVariables": false
    },
    "aliases": {
      "utils": "@/lib/utils",
      "components": "@/components"
    }
  }
```

**6th:** In `vite.config.js` defined `__dirname`. Otherwise, It might give you problems.

```
   //because __dirname was showing undefined
   const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
   const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
```

> **vite.config.js**

```
    import path from "path"
    import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
    import { defineConfig } from "vite"
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

    // because __dirname was showing undefined
    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
    const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [react()],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./"),
        },
      },
    })
```

**7th** (optional):
`path` variable also might cause problem. you can try running (so you can import "path" without error)

```
`npm i -D @types/node`
```

Only exception to yours folder structure is, my
**components** and **lib** folders are in the root folder(Not inside src).

[image: My File structure]

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks! Just one additional thing I had to do was call command: npx shadcn-ui@latest add {component-name}

Comment: @deathrace Your'e welcome. Yeah, this is the way to add component in a project after finishing configuration. I haven't added it because I only added steps related to configuration only.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you look at their docs (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation), just to let you know, the recommendation is to use Typescript, since also their components are written that way.

Apart from that, if you still want to stick with Javascript, I would suggest using the second jsconfig since your files/folders for the app are contained in a folder called **src**.

jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Also when checking the docs again (https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation) they have an example for the **components.json** file which looks like the following:

```
{
  ...
  "aliases": {
    "utils": "~/lib/utils",
    "components": "~/components"
}
```

So maybe try using a '~' instead of a '@'. Also you could try e.g. '~/src/components'.

Comment: the recommendation is typescript but their new cli asks if you want to use typescript or not - "Would you like to use TypeScript (recommended)? no/yes". I tried your recommended fixes and it still does not work. same error

Comment: Hava you also tried using an absolute path instead of a relative one in your index.js? So e.g.: '../components/ui/button' (I guess that should be right regarding your folder structure, but not sure)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following changes, based on some recommendations in stackflow and then experimenting. This also works fine in the build.
Note: I selected NON-ts version but did create a tsconfig.json by hand.
tsconfig.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
    "@/*": ["./src/@/*"]
}
```

components.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://ui.shadcn.com/schema.json",
    "style": "default",
    "rsc": false,
    "tsx": false,
    "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "src/index.css",
    "baseColor": "slate",
    "cssVariables": true
  },
    "aliases": {
    "components": "src/@/components",
    "utils": "src/@/lib/utils"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import path from "path"
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve('./src/@/') },
            { find: '@/components', replacement: path.resolve('./src/@/components/') 
        },
            { find: '@/lib', replacement: path.resolve('./src/@/lib/') },
        ],
    },
})
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I used export default, and it worked fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

jsconfig.json like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "tailwind.config.tsss"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import path from "path"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
})
```

Then move components and lib folder into src folder. This worked for me.